# JavaScript show a input type file on anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is as follows:

```
 <div class="fifty">
    <label>Credit report</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="credtireport-link" name="credtireport-link" value="<?php echo $creditreport; ?>">

    <input type="file" name="creditreport" id="creditreport" <?php if($creditreport!=""){?> style="display:none" <?php } ?> >
    <?php if($creditreport!="") { ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="showfile();">Edit File</a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
  <div class="fifty">
    <label>Employer’s ref</label>
    <input type="hidden" id="employerref-link" name="employerref-link" value="<?php echo $employeer_ref_url; ?>">

    <input type="file" name="employerref" id="employerref" <?php if($employeer_ref_url!=""){?> style="display:none" <?php } ?>>
     <?php if($employeer_ref_url=="") { ?>
    <a href="#" onclick="showfile();">Edit File</a>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

I want to write a function in JavaScript which is called on edit file anchor click and will show the respective input type file.

Explanation: if some one clicked on anchor of credit report then it should show only `<input type="file" name="creditreport" id="creditreport">`.

My JavaScript code:

```
function showfile()
{
    var id=$(this).parent().find('input[type="file"]').toggle();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If only I had a nickle for every-time I asked someone to write code for me!

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani i have written a code not work's

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Also see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @palaѕн jsFiddle didn't works with php

Comment: Then use [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Comment: @palaѕн please check this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gzgf9sy1/

Comment: i want to show and hide the respective input type file on click on anchor edit file

Comment: The file input is not being rendered always, instead of hiding the whole input with php, try hiding it with the style attribute

Comment: @MarkE ok then how can i show it again on click on button

Comment: @TalhaAslam your javascript is ok. But with the if else add the attribute `style="display:none"` instead of not showing the input

Comment: @MarkE i have updated the code please check but still didn't works

Comment: @TalhaAslam when you are refering to `this` you are refering to the `window` object. You have to add it as a paramerter to use it. `<a href="#" onclick="showfile(this);">Edit File</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<a href="#" onclick="showfile(this);">Edit File</a>
```

javascript

```
function showfile(el) {
  var id = $(el).prev(":file").toggle();
  return false;
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/MjZkZvFjlqj4a8HffYaF?p=preview

Comment: It takes to the top of page can you help me to solve this issue as well?

Comment: it takes me top top of page please helo

Comment: @TalhaAslam Replace `#` at `<a>` element `href` with closest `<input type="file">` element `id`, e.g., `<a href="#employerref" onclick="showfile(this);">Edit File</a>`; see version 3 at http://plnkr.co/edit/MjZkZvFjlqj4a8HffYaF?p=preview

Comment: @TalhaAslam You could alternatively replace `<a>` element with `<button>` element, to prevent navigation